# How to determine which point lies in which polygon from a list of multiple polygons

Tags: python, json, geolocation

I am new to python and currently working with Json file and I need to determine the location of each tweet and represent the grid in which they are present with the count of tweets in each grid cell.I tried comparing the xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax values of the polygon but it doesn't seems to be working. 
Any sort of advice would be helpful.
This the function which i have used to return the grid_id but it returns only 3 gird ids , implying that all the tweets were made from those 3 grids, which is not the case

```
lt =[]
def match_tweets():

    for d in dic.values():
        for x in lst:

            if ((x['xmin'][0]<= tweet_long[1][0][0] and tweet_long[1][0][0]<=x['xmax'][0]) and (x['ymin'][0]<=tweet_lat[0][0][0] and tweet_lat[0][0][0]<x['ymax'][0])):
                x['count']+=1
                return lst.append(x['grid_id'])
```

The data in dic looks like this

```
    {0: [[[-37.95935781]], [[144.92340088]], [['melbourne']]],
     1: [[[-37.95935781]], [[144.92340088]], [['melbourne']]],
     2: [[[-37.95935781]], [[144.92340088]], [['melbourne']]],
     3: [[[-37.95935781]], [[144.92340088]], [['melbourne']]],
     4: [[[-37.95935781]], [[144.92340088]], [['melbourne']]],
     5: [[[-37.94917514]], [[144.92501796]], [['tb', 'tasmania']]],
```

The data in lst looks like

```
    [{'id': 'A1',
    'xmin': [144.7],
    'xmax': [144.85],
    'ymin': [-37.65],
    'ymax': [-37.5],
    'coordinates': [[[144.7, -37.5],
     [144.85, -37.5],
     [144.85, -37.65],
     [144.7, -37.65],
     [144.7, -37.5]]],
     'count': 0},
```

Comment: Do you want to program the algorithm for point-in-polygon yourself or can you use a readily available package for that?

Comment: can you add a short example of what is in dic and lst, also did you mean to append to lt?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I can use the readily available packages for like

Comment: @IanTurton yeah , for dic it goes like this{ 0: [[[-37.95935781]], [[144.92340088]], [['melbourne']]],
 1: [[[-37.95935781]], [[144.92340088]], [['melbourne']]],
 2: [[[-37.95935781]], [[144.92340088]], [['melbourne']]],...
and for lst the values are 

[{'id': 'A1',
  'xmin': [144.7],
  'xmax': [144.85],
  'ymin': [-37.65],
  'ymax': [-37.5],
  'coordinates': [[[144.7, -37.5],
    [144.85, -37.5],
    [144.85, -37.65],
    [144.7, -37.65],
    [144.7, -37.5]]],
  'count': 0},...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your data structures are pretty horrible. If you can, try to lose all the lists of lists of lists... I picked the first elements of your list and dictionary below.

I recommend using [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/).

```
from shapely.geometry import *
```

You can create [Polygon geometries](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#polygons):

```
something = Polygon(lst_thing[0]['coordinates'][0])
```

You can create [Point geometries](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#points):

```
something_else = Point(d[0][0][0][0], d[0][1][0][0])  # sweet jesus...
```

And you can determine [relationships](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#binary-predicates) between geometries, for example checking if a Point is in or on the border of a Polygon:

```
something_else.intersects(something)  # -> True/False
```